# I want to INSERT data into my table IF the submit button has been pressed. I have this so far

Tags: php, html, mysqli

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Sign up page</title>
</head>
<body>



        <form method="get" action="signup_redirect.php">
            username: <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="username"><br>
            Password: <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="password"><br>
            <input type="submit" value="Create Account">
        </form>
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
$dbCon = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "test");

if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    echo "Failed to connect" .mysqli_connect_error();
}
?>
</body>
</html>
```

So I have this form connected to my database, but I'm not sure how to insert the data when the `SUBMIT` button has been pressed.

Comment: Usually I'd recommend just a normal INSERT query, but given that you want user-input for this, have a look at http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php - you want to use prepared statements so that you are protected against SQL-injection. Then you'll need `INSERT INTO...` instead of the `SELECT` examples. Example here: http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_prepared_statements.asp

Comment: http://www.sourcecodester.com/tutorials/php/4341/how-create-login-page-phpmysql.html

Comment: Make sure the action path. If the action is to its file, better to fill it empty. Action=""

Answer (score 0):

Here in html form and in php you are using different methods. in HTML you have **GET** and in PHP you have **POST** checking. for Authentication better use POST method. so lets change your code like this:

**HTML**:

```
<form method="post" action="signup_redirect.php">
                username: <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="username"><br>
                Password: <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="password"><br>
                <input type="submit" value="Create Account">
            </form>
```

**PHP**:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
$dbCon = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "test");

if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    echo "Failed to connect" .mysqli_connect_error();
}
?>
```

My database structure:
    [image]

Comment: dude i wrote problem where it was ... if OP wants he/she can change it with post...

Comment: you should not suggest bad coding practice in your answers... edit your answer...

Comment: hint: (the best approach is that Dest now edits their answer to further improve it and show the OP how it *should* be done. )

Comment: @Martin thanks for kind answer... i hate when someone like that guy comes  and puts only blames...

Comment: @Dest I can see your point of view, but in this instance they do have a point, you should **edit** your post and change everything to `POST` rather than to `GET`

Comment: @Martin I agree with your and dest's point but.. if you are answering then its better you should follow right coding practices, Even if you find me doing the same anywhere please let me know. I dont have any personal issues with anyone... if dest edits answer then I will get back my downvote.

Comment: @easycoder you also have good point but you can tell that without blame like martin told...

Comment: I did not blame you.. please check my comments, I just suggested you to make few changes in your answer... we are community, everyone has a right to share their thoughts.

Comment: The code now works but when i enter the data and click submit it should enter these values into my table right? But when i got to phpmyadmin nothing has been added?

Comment: @Dan oh, you must add insert query for mysql show your DB structure and i will add insert query to my answer

Comment: i will put it in the question

Comment: @Dan already updated... if you will change with your values it will work

Comment: the code doesnt work now it comes up with parsing error